# Setting and using variable in different scopes not working in C

Tags: c, arrays, variables, scope, printf

I print out a variable in two different scopes (variable is visible to both), and am getting different results in the console.

I am trying to make dynamic arrays in C. I've written functions that deal with allocating memory,and now am at the last step of simply verifying that EVERYTHING works right. Below is my test program.

When printing out the values of an array in `LOOP A`, I get the following

```
<<0:2000000000>>

<<1:2000000000>>

<<2:2000000000>>
```

But when printing out that the very same values in the same array in loop B, I am getting gibberish, perhaps the result of an uninitialized index in the array:

```
<<0:/*-*/20975841/*-*/22222222>>

<<1:2222222222>>

<<2:2222222222>>
```

Here are the structs and Macros

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <objc/objc.h>

#define PRINT_STR(str) {\
printf(str);\
}

typedef struct {
    int lastIndx;
    int *array;

}one_D_Array;

//##################Helper Functions#############################

int sizeint = 1;
void print_Array(int *array, int lastInd) {
    for (int i = 0; i <=lastInd ; i++) {
        printf("%d",array[i]);
    }
}


void printVal(int val) {
    printf("%d", val);
}

int countOfArray(int *ar){
    int sizf = sizeof(ar) / sizeof(int) + 1;
    printVal(sizf);
    return sizf;
}

int scanInt(){
    int begin;
    scanf("%d",&begin);
    return begin;
}
//##################1D Array#############################

one_D_Array init_one_D_Array() {
    one_D_Array array;
    array.array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    array.array[0] = (int)malloc(sizeof(int));
    array.lastIndx = 0;
    return array;

}

one_D_Array addToArray(one_D_Array array, int toAdd) {
//    int *newAr;
//    newAr.array = (int *)malloc(array.lastIndx * sizeof(int))
    array.array[array.lastIndx] = (int)malloc(sizeof(int));
    array.array[array.lastIndx] = toAdd;
    array.lastIndx++;

    return array;
}

//##################2D Array#############################

int **init_2d_Array(void) {
    int **newarr = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *));
    return newarr;
}

void print2dArray(int **array, int len, int lastInd) {
    for (int range = 0; range <= lastInd; range++) {
        for (int r2 = 0; r2 < len; r2++) {
            printVal(array[range][r2]);
        }
    }
}

int **addArrayToArray(int **array, int *toAdd, int oldcount){//This should add a 1d array to a 2d array

    if (array == NULL ) {printf("Array must be initialized"); exit(1);}
    else array[oldcount] = malloc(sizeof(int *));
    array[oldcount] = toAdd;
    return array;
}
```

And main()

```
int main()
{
    PRINT_STR("Please enter a number");
    int ttlLoops = scanInt(); //Total Number of loops run
    int count = 0; //How many times the loop has run in total
    int **tu_D = init_2d_Array();
//LOOP A
    for (int x = 0; x < ttlLoops;x++) {
        one_D_Array ar2 = init_one_D_Array(); //Initializing a one_D_Array
        ar2.lastIndx = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          ar2 = addToArray(ar2, 2); //Adding to the one dimensional array an int
        }
        *tu_D = *addArrayToArray(tu_D, ar2.array, count); //Adding the one dimensional array to a 2d array
        printf("\n<<%d:",count");
        print_Array(tu_D[count], 9); //Printing the 1D array just saved above into the 2D array
        PRINT_STR(">>\n");
        count ++;


    }
//LOOP A 
//LOOP B
    for (int i =0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("\n<<%d:",i);
        print_Array(tu_D[i], 9);
        PRINT_STR(">>\n");
    }
   return 0;
//LOOP B
}
```

Comment: Can you post **all** your code? Including `print_Array` and `PRINT_STR`?

Comment: And the various init and add functions.

Comment: I've just added all the relevant code

Comment: You have some strange code there. Why are you casting the return value of `malloc` to `int`?

Comment: Although I don't see you using it in this code, the `countOfArray` function is also incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the following problems with your code:

1. Problem with the following lines in `init_one_D_Array`.

   ```
   array.array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
   array.array[0] = (int)malloc(sizeof(int));
   ```

   You shouldn't cast the return value of `malloc` in the first line. The second line is strange. I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish but it is not only unnecessary but it also will likely lead to memory leaks. Replace those lines with

   ```
   array.array = malloc(sizeof(int));
   ```
2. Problem with the following line in `addToArray`.

   ```
   array.array[array.lastIndx] = (int)malloc(sizeof(int));
   ```

   I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish with the above statement. However, judging by the name of the function, you need:

   ```
   array.array = realloc(array.array, sizeof(int)*(array.lastIndx+1));
   ```
3. Problem with the following line in `addArrayToArray`.

   ```
   else array[oldcount] = malloc(sizeof(int *));
   ```

   This problem is similar to the previous problem. Once again, judging by the name of your function, you need:

   ```
   else array = realloc(array, sizeof(int*)*(oldcount+1));
   ```
4. Problem with the following line in `main`.

   ```
   *tu_D = *addArrayToArray(tu_D, ar2.array, count); //Adding the one dimensional array to a 2d array
   ```

   Your comment in that line and what the code does are not in agreement. You are simply assigning the first `int*` from the returned value of `addArrayToArray` to the first element of `tu_D`. You need:

   ```
   tu_D = addArrayToArray(tu_D, ar2.array, count);
   ```

Working program at http://ideone.com/yD6W4y.